# Is there a way to delete unused collections?

Tags: collections

Just learned about instancing in Blender and noticed that I have some unneeded collections. I tried to find a way to delete them but the only thing I managed to do is leave an empty collection.

[image: Some of the collections present in the document]

[image: Collection.001 is empty but still a chooseable option]

Comment: Only with python script

Comment: There is an option in File > Clean Up > Unused data blocks, which does what it says. I don't think it'll do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this script:

```
import bpy

for eachCol in bpy.data.collections:
    
    if len(eachCol.all_objects) == 0:
        
        bpy.data.collections.remove(eachCol)
```

Comment: I assume this deletes any collection if there are no objects in them. In case anyone finds this useful, I found two more scripts, the first removes the collection but not the objects, and the second removes both the collection specified and its objects. https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/removing-collections-through-the-blender-python-api/

Answer (score 3):

[image]

With pre-installed addon "Collection Manadger"
M>Specials>Remove Empty Collections